# Setting Image Sizes In Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, photoshop

Windows phone asks for specific image sizes when submitting an application. When I take the image I wanna use and resize it to the dimensiond they want it distorts the image. If I keep it proportional Ill never get the exact sizes they need. What do you guys do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Photoshop. Open the image, choose "Image" > "Canvas Size". That will adjust the size of the image without distorting it. I am sure you can also use any of the free image applications like gimp http://www.gimp.org/